# FancyBox image viewer and retina displays

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

My understanding is that this will ensure a device with a retina display will display the image as best as possible:

```
<img src="image_400x300.jpg" width="200" height="150" />
```

...and this is some FancyBox demo code

```
<a id="fb_image" href="image_800x600.jpg" title="The Title">
    <img src="image_400x300.jpg" width="200" height="150" />
</a>
```

...The thumbnail in the main web page will support a retina display, but I don't see how the image when opened with FancyBox can be programmed to support retina.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I've just added a pull request for retina support in fancyBox, have a look:
https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/pull/420

Comment: For TYPO3 you can use this option with this version: 
https://github.com/taywa/cl_jquery_fancybox or have a look if this pull request has found its way into main version: https://github.com/svewap/cl_jquery_fancybox/pull/2

Answer (score 0):

You may need to hack it using the `beforeShow` call back like :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#fb_image").fancybox({
  beforeShow: function(){
   var retinaWidth = this.width / 2; // set new image retina display width
   $(".fancybox-image").css({"width":retinaWidth,"height":"auto"}); // apply new retina display size to img
   // set new values for parent container
   this.width = retinaWidth;
   this.height = $(".fancybox-image").innerHeight();
  }
 }); // fancybox
}); // ready
```

If you are using this code for more than one image, use a `class` instead

```
<a class="fb_image" href...
```

and

```
$(".fb_image").fancybox()
```